# Find difference between two dates in years, with the remainder expressed in days, in Python

Tags: python, output, date-arithmetic

How does one find the difference between two dates, if the output should be expressed in years with the remainder expressed in days?

***Example 1***: if the two dates are `June 1, 1981` and `August 23, 2001,` then the result should be *`20 years and 83 days`*.

***Example 2***: if the two dates are `January 1, 2002` and `December 30, 2003,` then the result should be *`1 year and 363 days`*.

I'm not concerned with the *formatting* of the results; I just need to know the most Pythonic way of calculating the number of years and days.

Thank you!

Comment: What Python code have you already tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `datetime`, a built-in module, you can get the number of days easily.

```
>>> import datetime

>>> foo = datetime.date(2001, 8, 23) - datetime.date(1981, 6, 1)
>>> foo
datetime.timedelta(days=7388)
>>> foo.days
7388

>>> bar = datetime.date(2003, 12, 30) - datetime.date(2002, 1, 1)
>>> bar
datetime.timedelta(days=728)
>>> bar.days
728
```

The `dateutil` module can give you the number of years, but the number of months is also thrown in.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

>>> relativedelta(datetime.date(2001, 8, 23), datetime.date(1981, 6, 1))
relativedelta(years=+20, months=+2, days=+22)

>>> relativedelta(datetime.date(2003, 12, 30), datetime.date(2002, 1, 1))
relativedelta(years=+1, months=+11, days=+29)
```

Be careful while using the number of months, though. A month is not defined as well as a day. The 11 months in the previous example are a mix of six 31-day months, four 30-day months and one 28-day month. So, in general, you cannot use it to obtain the number of days. I recommend writing a function to get the difference in the form you want.

```
import calendar
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

def get_delta(date2, date1):
    '''calculate the delta between two datetime.date objects (date2 the newer date)'''

    number_of_leap_years = sum(1
                               for yr in range(date1.year, date2.year + 1)
                               if calendar.isleap(yr))
    number_of_years = relativedelta(date2, date1).years

    total_number_of_days = (date2 - date1).days
    number_of_days = total_number_of_days
                     - 365 * number_of_years
                     - number_of_leap_years

    return f'{number_of_years} years, {number_of_days} days'
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm not _entirely_ happy with the answer because I was hoping that there'd be some Python module that would give the answer without having to manually create a function to convert months to days, but your function does the trick, and is the best answer submitted, and your `get_delta()` function _seems_ to do exactly what I need (though I haven't thoroughly tested it yet). Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the datetime and relativedelta modules.

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

start_date = datetime.datetime(1981,6,1)
end_date = datetime.datetime(2002,1,1)

difference_in_years = relativedelta(end_date, start_date)
print(difference_in_years)
```

Comment: Daniel, thank you. But I tried out your code and the result comes back expressed in years and *months*, not years and days. I was unaware of the `relativedelta` module though, so I *may* be able to figure out what I need from here. Thank you again.